# How can I lazily evaluate a list difference in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way of evaluating a list difference between infinite lists? For example, `([1..] \\ [2*n | n <- [1..]])` should evaluate to `[1,3,5,7,`...`]`. Unfortunately, it seems to be forcing evaluation on either the first or second list, or both. Is there a way of avoiding this to get answers? Even using `take 5 ([1..] \\ [2*n | n <- [1..]])` doesn't evaluate to `[1,3,5,7,9]`, which would be obviously correct. Note, the `\\` operator is imported from Data.List.

Comment: How would you write an algorithm to do this by hand? How far through the two lists would you have to look to conclude, "okay, this value occurs in the first list but never in the second"?

Comment: Oh, of course. If it's unsorted, there wouldn't be a way of knowing it wasn't at the end. I guess sometimes I rely on Haskell's magic too much without thinking :)

Comment: @BrainFRZ I think "If it's unsorted, then there wouldn't be a way knowing it wasn't at the end" is too strong. Certainly the assumptions `(\\)` makes (namely, none) don't give it a way to know if a particular element might occur later. But I bet I could cook up other special list properties that are not sorted-ness that would nevertheless give you a way to choose when to stop looking for a particular element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the lists are sorted, you may use the [`data-ordlist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) package.

```
Data.List.Ordered> take 5 ([1..] `minus` [2,4..])
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I wouldn't be able to guarantee the lists are sorted. Would this not work at all if it were unsorted? Or would the solution be to sort the lists and then use this? That then begs the question: can sorting be lazy?

Comment: @BrainFRZ, no, because you could always find a smaller element later on in the list.  (The intuition is that there's not really any way to know anything about a list without iterating through it.  I think this intuition can be formalized with something like Rice's theorem)

Comment: @BrainFRZ Right, this library will not work correctly at all if the lists are unsorted. Sorting cannot be lazy. If you can't know the lists are sorted, then you will have to know and exploit some other special structure in the lists to be able to do what you ask.

Comment: Let me know if this should be a separate question, or if it's off-topic. But, if I differentiate the functions to find their vertices, would I be able to use that and monotonicity to do this? Then I'd only need to sort the vertices, right?

Comment: @BrainFRZ Hm. I'm not sure I understood that. I suspect you should indeed open a new question, if only to give yourself a few extra characters to explain your goals, the approach you have in mind, and the jargon you're using.

Comment: It seems like the question about sorting lazily is already answered here: https://ondergetekende.nl/lazy-sorting-in-python.html Someone created an algorithm to perform a lazy sort with a faster result than a C-optimized TimSort when only sorting about 45% of the list. As far as differentiation, I'll pursue that further on my own and see if it amounts to anything.

Comment: @BrainFRZ The techniques discussed there are interesting and useful, but not lazy enough: even if all you care about is the very first element of the sorted list, you still have to look at the very least at every element of the unsorted list to produce it. If your unsorted list is infinite...

Comment: @BrainFRZ (Indeed, for taking just the elements from the front of the list, Haskell's built-in `sort` is already appropriately lazy in that sense. Observing the first k elements of a sorted list of length n takes O(n*log k) time.)